# How to prove that $\mathbb{E}Y1_A = \mathbb{E}X1_A, \forall A \in G \iff \mathbb{E}YZ = \mathbb{E}XZ, \forall Z \in L^\infty(G)$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, monotone-class-theorem

I am trying to prove this statement using the monotone class theorem for functions :

> $\mathbb{E}Y1_A = \mathbb{E}X1_A, \forall A \in G \iff \mathbb{E}YZ = \mathbb{E}XZ, \forall Z \in L^\infty(G)$

I think I managed to prove $\Rightarrow$ :

Since $L^\infty(G)$ is a vector space of functions from $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ containing the constant functions and if $f_n \subset L^\infty(G)$ is a non-decreasing bounded function series  from $L^\infty(G)$, then $lim_nf_n \in L^\infty(G)$ and let $C \subset L^\infty(G)$ be the set of all $1_A$ such that $A\in G$, then $C$ is stable under multiplication and we can apply the monontone class theorem :

$L^0_b(\sigma(C)) \subset L^\infty(G)$ and hence for $Z:= 1_A$ for a certain $A \in G$, we have that since is $\sigma(C)-$mesureable, then $Z$ is $L^\infty(G)-$mesureable and we have that $\mathbb{E}Y1_A = \mathbb{E}Y1_A, \forall A \in G \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}YZ = \mathbb{E}YZ, \forall Z \in L^\infty(G)$

But for the other statement to prove, I am stuck. How can I get from $L^\infty(G)$ functions to indicator functions ?

Any idea ?

Comment: indicator functions of measurable sets are in $L^\infty$?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, that is what I proved. Now I am trying to prove the other direction

Comment: I think you need to spend some time carefully thinking about what you've already written in that case. In the question, you say you have proved $\implies$ but in the comment indicate you've proved the other direction. But the other direction is trivial and certainly doesn't take any of the machinery you've used in the post. Indeed, if $A$ is a measurable set then $1_A$ is a measurable and bounded function so is in $L^\infty$ by definition of $L^\infty$. For the forward direction, you need to use the kind of machinery indicated in the post - e.g. approximate measurable functions by simple ones.